# Devise: When overriding Registrations Controller#create how can I preserve entered form fields on Fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've overridden the Registrations Controller for Devise, more precisely the **#create** action, I took the code directly from the Repo:

```
def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)
  if resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
      expire_data_after_sign_in!
      respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else #what code do I need here to preserve user entered field(s)?
    clean_up_passwords resource
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

It's all working fine for the case in which the resource(user) is valid and saved, But when the **user isn't valid**, and it redirects back to the view, the problem is that **it's not preserving the fields the user already entered.**

Example:

**Registrations#new** view, I enter user info,

[image: registrations#new]

After submit and validation failure *and Redirect*, User input isn't preserved....

[image: registrations#new_2]

How can I make Devise preserve user entered fields in **registrations#create** override?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the value of resource during a failed validation? Nothing I see would cause the fields to be blank so perhaps that will provide more information.  Also, are you receiving validation errors (ie, passwords don't match, etc?)  As an aside, what is the point of overriding the function if you're copying it verbatim?

Comment: Actually, my original problem (the reason to override) was the need to use another navigational format, in this case: mobile. If you can point in the right way on how to do this with devise, I'd really appreciate it! (with the default format :html the fields are being preserved well) -Thanks for the reply, sir

Comment: Let me be sure I understand, you're using the config.navigational_formats = {:html, :mobile} in your initializer, presumably with authenticatble_on_xhr?

Comment: Yes, sir. I am using the config.navigational_formats = {:html, :mobile}, but not the authenticatble_on_xhr?, and devise isn't responding well at all for mobile views, it interchanges them in some places to :html.

Comment: I don't have a problem with this with devise. How are you checking for mobile?

Comment: I took some time, but I was able to figure it out thanks to the Devise wiki; https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Make-Devise-work-with-other-formats-like-mobile,-iPhone-and-iPad---Rails-specific
I followed those steps, with some customizations I had to do that were app-specific, and it started to work!